# Notice Undefined variable php, teniendo las variables definidas

Tags: php, variables, undefined

tengo 4 variables definidas en mi código pero al ejecutarlo me tira el error, me he fijado todas las lineas por posibles errores tipográficos pero nada.
Me muestra el siguiente error :

Tomo la linea 21 como ejemplo

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: regMARC in ProcesoWebConfirmUPD.php on line 21

La línea 21 es la siguiente

> $marca       = utf8_encode($regMARC["marcPROD"]);

acá el php donde tengo definidas las variables:

```
    <?php
    // PROCESO WEB MARKET UPD

    // conectar al servidor
    include "conexion.inc";
    // capturar datos del formulario
    $id          = $_POST["ID"];
    $marca       = utf8_decode($_POST["MARC"]);
    $descripcion = utf8_decode($_POST["DESC"]);
    $origen      = $_POST["ORIG"];
    $categoria   = $_POST["CAT"];
    // crear sentencia SQL para INSERTAR registro
    $sql  = "UPDATE productos SET ";
    $sql .= "marcPROD = '$marca', ";
    $sql .= "descPROD = '$descripcion', ";
    $sql .= "origPROD = '$origen', ";
    $sql .= "nomCAT = $categoria ";            
    $sql .= "WHERE idPROD = $id";
    ?>
```

Acá donde uso las variables:

```
<?php
    // PROCESO WEB MARKET CONFIRM UPD

    // conectar al Servidor de Base de Datos
    include "conexion.inc";
    // capturar ID a buscar desde el formulario
    $id = $_POST["ID"];
    // crear sentencia SQL para buscar el ID
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE idPROD=$id";
    // ejecutar sentecia SQL
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conex);
    // controlar existencia
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        // mensaje de error
        header("location:errorPage.php?MSG=ID INEXISTENTE");
    } else {
        // cargar registro
        $regPROD = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // convertir datos
        $id          = $regPROD["idPROD"];
        $marca       = utf8_encode($regMARC["marcPROD"]);
        $descripcion = utf8_encode($regDESC["descPROD"]);
        $origen      = $regORIG["origPROD"];
        $categoria   = $regCAT["nomCAT"];
    } // endif
?>
```

Si alguien sabe donde puede estar el error, o que me esta faltando, o donde me esta faltando definir la variable, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Dónde dices que tienes DEFINIDA la variable `regMARC`?? Estás leyendo un índice de `regMARC` peeero... dónde dices que la estás creando y asignándole algo????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar todos los `$regXXXX` por `$regPROD` dento de ese `else`:

```
// cargar registro
$regPROD = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// convertir datos
$id          = $regPROD["idPROD"];
$marca       = utf8_encode($regPROD["marcPROD"]);
$descripcion = utf8_encode($regPROD["descPROD"]);
$origen      = $regPROD["origPROD"];
$categoria   = $regPROD["nomCAT"];
```

**Explicación:**

Cuando haces la asignación del resultado de la consulta `mysql_fetch_array($result)` lo estás haciendo en la variable `$regPROD`, que almacena ese resultado en forma de matriz dentro de esa variable.

A partir de alli llamas a sus distintos valores mediante sus claves, las cuales son distintas, pero no el nombre de la variable `$regPROD`, que  permanece invariable.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era ese el problema.

Comment: Me alegro!  Si consideras que esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta pulsa sobre Aceptar (no esoy seguro que ponga eso, quizas es un tick o una casilla) debajo de las flechas donde esta la respuesta, para dejarla marcada como aceptada y así la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$regMARC` no está definida en ningún lugar del código...

Te falta algo así como: `$regMARC = loquesea`